# Generalized Catalan number satisfying recursive definition

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, catalan-numbers, sorting

Wondering if the numbers satisfying the following relationship have a name or known closed-form solution. They show up in enumerating possible configurations of swaps during the execution of a bubble sort.

\begin{equation}
F_{k,n} =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ k = 0} \\
k & \text{ n = 1} \\
F_{k-1,n} + F_{k+1,n-1} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Note that $F_{1,n}$ is the nth Catalan number. The matrix of the first few numbers is:

\begin{array}
01&2&5&14\\
2&5&14&42\\
3&9&28&90\\
4&14&48&165\
\end{array}

Comment: They may or may not have a special name, but there is a fairly straightforward way to describe them. These numbers are simply the number of ways of reaching a lattice point in a gridwalk where you cannot cross the $x=y$ line.

Comment: The fourth row seems to be [OEIS sequence A002057](https://oeis.org/A002057). Searching for the third row also brings up results that might be relevant.

Comment: If you read your table along the diagonals starting from the upper left corner you get $1,2,2,3,5,5,4,9,14,14,5,14,28,42$. This seems to be exactly [OEIS A115126](https://oeis.org/A115126).  You can find a closed form there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are sometimes known as the *ballot numbers*. Imagine an election where candidate $A$ received $n+k$ votes, and candidate $B$ received $n$ votes. Then $F_{k,n}$ is the number of ways to order the ballots such that $A$ is strictly ahead of $B$ throughout the counting process when the ballots are counted in that order.

They are given by the explicit formula
$$
F_{k,n}=\binom{2n+k}{n}\frac{k}{k+2n}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! In fact, I am counting preference rankings, so that checks out. Any suggestions on where to read more?

Comment: Well, the Wikipedia article on Bertrand's ballot theorem is good, and I think that [Four proofs of the ballot theorem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252059419_Four_Proofs_of_the_Ballot_Theorem) by Marc Renault is very interesting. There's also lots of relevant info on the OEIS for this sequence: https://oeis.org/A009766, with more sources.